# Xcode 11 beta 3 crashing when using NavigationLink, @EnvironmentObject and List together

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, combine

I've got a strange crash in **SwiftUI / Xcode 11 beta 3** with code like the one below (I've kept only the bare minimum to show the behavior):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class AppData: BindableObject  {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<AppData, Never>()

    init() { }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView() ) {
                Text("link")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData
//  @ObjectBinding var appData = AppData() -> Works 

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
            Text("C")
        }
    }
}
```

The `BindableObject` is injected in `SceneDelegate.swift` like this:

```swift
....
        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()
                                           .environmentObject(AppData()))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
....
```

When following the `NavigationLink` it crashes with

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

If I remove the `List` view from the detail view it works OK. The same if I use `@ObjectBinding` instead (like in the commented line in my code).

The same code used to work in previous betas.

Comment: I am having the same type of crash.  This is the partial error message from the console:  error: module importing failed: invalid token (rlm_lldb.py, line 37)
  File "temp.py", line 1, in <module>

dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI14NavigationLinkVyxGAA4ViewAAMc
  Referenced from: ... (it goes on from there with the referencing path, etc.

Comment: Have you upgraded your device to beta 3?

Comment: @Jake : it's the simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in Xcode 11 beta 3. The old behaviour will likely return.

From https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input as of July 4th 2019:

> Step 4
>
> In Xcode 11 beta 3, the LandmarkDetail view doesn’t automatically access the UserData object in the view hierarchy’s environment. The workaround for this is to add the environmentObject(_:) modifier to the LandmarkDetail view.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is by design. When you create DetailView(), it is disconnected from the hierarchy, and hence it does not inherit the same environment.

If you change your ContentView to the following, it won't crash. I think I remember having a similar problem with modals:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView().environmentObject(appData) ) {
                Text("link")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of the `@EnvironmentObject` then ? If I have to pass it explicitly to each view I navigate to why not use a normal parameter (@binding or not) ?

Comment: Well, not **ALL** views. Only those like DetailView and some other cases, for the majority, @EnvironmentObject still serves its purpose.

Comment: I think we can agree that at the time DetailView is created, because it has no parent, it cannot inherit an environment. What is arguable is wether SwiftUI should attach the environment automatically when it is inserted (presented) into the hierarchy. I think it shouldn't, or otherwise it may risk overwriting a specific environment you may have set. I think SwiftUI is just cautions and if you want it to inherit the environment, you must do it yourself. It's my opinion, I have not read it anywhere.

Comment: I see your point although I don't agree with it :-) If I want to create "manually" a data flow trough my app I'd use normal params in the view's initializers. The environment should be accessible everywhere, like it did in beta 1&2.

Comment: Are you sure it worked like that in beta 1&2. I recall having this problem at least a week ago.

Comment: Virtually any view except the initial one is created and accessed by some sort of NavigationLink anyway. The only example I could think of are the root views in a TabBar (and indeed they inherit the environment)

Comment: Yes, it worked, my test app worked just fine until I downloaded beta 3 this morning.

Comment: My app works fine with beta 2 as well.   I commented out both of the NavigationLinks in my code and got the same error.   module importing failed: invalid token (rlm_lldb.py, line 37) File "temp.py".  However, the error then referred to Gesture recognizer not found where it was expected, ie, Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI.  So both the NavigationLink files and the Gesture files are not in the files they are expected to be in.

Comment: This seems to be resolved in the GM build for iOS apps, but for watchOS apps the bug still exists.